# c: error with wchar_t array passing to a function?

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass a 3d wchar_t array to function called 'test_array', but I get a crash when it's used inside
 the function, moreover I get those compiling warnings:

-'passing argument 1 of 'test_array' from incompatible pointer type'

-'expected 'wchar_t ****' but argument is of type 'const wchar_t * (*)[2][6]''

and here is my complete program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test_array(wchar_t**** array){
    wprintf(array[0][0][0]);
}

int main(){
    const wchar_t *d[][2][6]={
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }},
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } }
    };
    wprintf(d[0][0][0]); //wprintf works fine here
    test_array(d); //but there is the crash
    getch();
}
```

so what's wrong, and what should I do to fix that?

Comment: @n.m. - This is discussing a different issue.  This post is of a more specific nature than the one you referenced.  Let it stand.

Comment: @ryyker Just curious, what are the two different issues you identify here? I only see one issue in both questions, namely the supposed interchangeability of arrays-of-arrays and pointers-to-pointers. There are about 9000 other questions on SO about this same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phenomenom by which an array becomes a pointer is called "decay":

```
char foo[] = "hello";
char* bar = foo; // DECAY!
```

So array decay is an implicit conversion between an array type and a pointer type. The compiler just has to take the address of the base of the array and be done with it. But an important thing to know about it is that it only works on the *first level* of an array: a `char[10]` can decay into a `char*`, but a `char[10][10]` cannot decay into a `char**`: it can only decay into a pointer of `char[10]`.

`char**` and `char[][]` are fundamentally different. In `char** x`, `x[0]` is a pointer to the first character of an array; but with `char y[10][10]`, `y[0]` is the 10-char array, not a pointer to it. However, this array can decay into a pointer.

So obviously, a `wchar_t[][][][]` is not the same as a `wchar_t****`. This is why your program crashes.

There is no obvious way to convert a 3D array into a pointer to pointers to pointers to pointers, and the storage requirements aren't the same. As multiple people already noted, you can change your function's prototype to accept a different pointer type.

Comment: nice explanation of decay!

Answer (score 1):

The `test_array(wchar_t****);` prototype is expecting a `wchar_t ****`, you have passed it a `const wchar_t*[][2][6]`.  One is a scaler, the other is a scaler that points to an array.   Although these forms can be used in *similar* ways, they are not the same.

***To eliminate the compiler error***, (which you should get with this mismatch) either change the prototype of `Test_array()`, or change the form of the variable you are passing it

***This modification*** of your code builds without errors because I have modified the prototype of `test_array()`.  (It runs also, only tested the ability to pass argument)

```
void test_array(const wchar_t* array[][2][6]){
    printf("%d", array[0][0][0][0]);
}

int main(){
    const wchar_t *d[][2][6]={
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }},
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
        { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } }
    };
    printf("%d", d[0][0][0][0]); //wprintf works fine here
    test_array(d); //but there is the crash
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler said, `wchar_t ****` is different from `const wchar_t * (*)[2][6]`. If you want to pass your array to the function, you need to change the prototype to:

```
void test_array(wchar_t* array[][2][6]) ;
```

Shortly, the argument is a pointer to a statically allocated array, which is different of a pointer of pointer of pointer...

Basically, you have:

```
void f(char c[][4]) {
    c[1][2] ; // is equivalent to *(c + 4 * 1 + 2), because the memory is continuous
}
```

But:

```
void g(char **c) {
    c[1][2]; // is equivalent to *(*(c + 1) + 2), because your memory is not continuous
}
```

With `char c[4][4]` you have a memory block of `4 * 4 * sizeof(char)` bytes allocated (a continuous block), but with `char **c` you would have basically 4 block of `4 * sizeof(char)` bytes allocated in differents places of your memory.

Comment: I am not sure your statements about _continuous_ or _not continuous_ memory are correct,  or what bearing that has on the fact that the form of the array passed was incorrect for the prototype.  Can you support  them?

Comment: @Holt ok, I tested doing 'void test_array(wchar_t* array[][2][6])' instead of 'void test_array(wchar_t**** array)', it works fine for me now, but I still don't know why I get the same warnings from the compiler as stated above?